# Pointer to sliced Eigen matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, slice, eigen

I have a function which takes a pointer to an Eigen matrix. I need to slice this matrix to several pieces and pass a portion of the matrix to the function. I want to avoid copying data, so I want to pass it with a pointer.

I slice a matrix, for example like this:

```
MatrixXd A;
// some operations with the matrix
// now I want something like this:
MatrixXd *B = &A(seq(2, 4), all);
```

The last line is invalid. How can I get a pointer to a piece of matrix so that it can still be treated as an Eigen matrix? Are there any workarounds? Again, I'd like to avoid creating new matrices as in my real program they are quite big.

Answer (score 4):

That's what `Eigen::Ref` was built for. See the section ["How to write generic, but non-templated function?"](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html)

Something like this:

```
void consume_matrix(const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::MatrixXd>& in);
void produce_matrix(Eigen::Ref<Eigen::MatrixXd> out);


void foo()
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd matrix = ...;
    produce_matrix(matrix.middleRows(start, len));
    consume_matrix(matrix.leftCols(len));
}
```

### Storing block references

Eigen doesn't come with a type that is well-suited to keep a "borrowed" block expression of a matrix. I wouldn't recommend `Ref` for this case because it is far too easy to make it point at temporary allocations which can easily lead to dangling pointers.

Ultimately, storing borrowed views is a fundamentally unsafe operation. But if you absolutely have to do it, I would use an `Eigen::Map`. At least that makes it clear you aren't owning the memory to which you refer. Something like this:

```
struct MatrixReference
{
  using map_type = Eigen::Map<
    Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::Unaligned, Eigen::OuterStride<> >;

  map_type matrix;

  template<class Derived>
  static map_type to_map(const Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>& matrix) noexcept
  {
    assert(matrix.innerStride() == 1);
    return map_type(const_cast<double*>(matrix.derived().data()),
                    matrix.rows(), matrix.cols(),
                    Eigen::OuterStride<>(matrix.outerStride()));
  }

  MatrixReference() noexcept
  : matrix(nullptr, 0, 0, Eigen::OuterStride<>(1))
  {}
  template<class Derived>
  explicit MatrixReference(const Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>& matrix) noexcept
    : matrix(to_map(matrix))
  {}
  MatrixReference(const MatrixReference&) = default;
  MatrixReference& operator=(const MatrixReference& o) noexcept
  {
    // placement-new because assignment would overwrite the content
    new (&matrix) map_type(o.matrix);
    return *this;
  }
};
int main()
{
  Eigen::MatrixXd mat = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(4, 5);
  MatrixReference ref(mat.topRows(2));
  std::cout << mat << "\n\n" << ref.matrix << "\n\n";
}
```

A slightly safer option is to keep a `shared_ptr` to the matrix and store the information what slice you use separately. Maybe like this:

```
struct CountedBlockRef
{
  std::shared_ptr<Eigen::MatrixXd> matrix;
  Eigen::Index first_row, first_col, rows, cols;

  using block_type = Eigen::Block<
    Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>;
  using const_block_type = Eigen::Block<
    const Eigen::MatrixXd, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic>;

  CountedBlockRef() noexcept
  : matrix(), first_row(), first_col(), rows(), cols()
  {}
  CountedBlockRef(std::shared_ptr<Eigen::MatrixXd> matrix,
                  Eigen::Index first_row, Eigen::Index first_col,
                  Eigen::Index rows, Eigen::Index cols) noexcept
    : matrix(std::move(matrix)),
      first_row(first_row),
      first_col(first_col),
      rows(rows),
      cols(cols)
  {}
  block_type block() noexcept
  { return matrix->block(first_row, first_col, rows, cols); }

  const_block_type block() const noexcept
  {
    const Eigen::MatrixXd& matrix = *this->matrix;
    return matrix.block(first_row, first_col, rows, cols);
  }
};
int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<Eigen::MatrixXd> matptr =
    std::make_shared<Eigen::MatrixXd>(Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(4, 5));
  CountedBlockRef aref(matptr, 0, 0, 2, 5);
  std::cout << *matptr << "\n\n" << aref.block() << '\n';
}
```

That way, the reference will remain valid even after resizing the matrix and dangling pointers are avoided. Only shrinking remains a threat but that is caught by assertions, assuming you compile with them.

Comment: I need a pointer, not a reference. In my case, the matrices are attributes of a class and if put as references, they must be initialised in place, so I put them as pointers to allow them to be initialised later. Can I have a _pointer_ to a block of matrix or the entire matrix, not a _reference_?

Comment: @Kaiyakha I extended my answer accordingly. But as I wrote, this is an unsafe way of using matrices.

Comment: Can I have the return type of `block` as `MatrixXd*` (or some of `std` pointers)? With this solution, I have to use `block_type` where I already have `MatrixXd*`.

Comment: @Kaiyakha No, an ```Eigen::Matrix``` always owns its data and deletes it when destroyed. So you cannot have a matrix pointing into the middle of a larger matrix. It's like the difference between string and string_view.

Comment: So I guess there is also no way to have several Eigen matrices sharing the same `data()` pointer, let alone pointers to such matrices, right?

Comment: @Kaiyakha not the Matrix type itself. Eigen has no type for shared ownership (like a ```shared_ptr```). You can only borrow it with a block expression or an ```Eigen::Map``` and handle the ownership yourself. I guess you could also make your own subclass of ```Eigen::Matrix``` that handles reference counting. https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_InheritingMatrix.html

Comment: For this reason I switched to Eigen::Ref or Eigen::Ref & for most of my function arguments. Can really recommend it. If you do that you can easily point to the same underlying matrix with multiple objects.