# How to use Eigen::Ref with STL Vector?

Tags: c++, eigen

currently, I'm working on a specific problem where I have an STL vector with several mapped Eigen vectors of different sizes which I would like to keep.
When writing a function to accept my stl vector with mapped eigen vectors, I always encounter a compiler error, stating that conversion could not be performed.

When simply working without the surrounding STL vector (i.e. `Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXd>`), everything works fine. However, once the STL vector comes into play, the given compiler error occurs:
My mwe looks as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/Core>

void EigenRefFunction(const std::vector<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXd>>& vec)
{
    for(int i=0;i<vec.size();++i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<vec[i].rows();++j)
        {
                    std::cout << i << "," << "j:\t" << vec[i](j) << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    //Examplary vector to map
    std::vector<double> vec1(10, 1.0);

    //Mapped vector
    std::vector<Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd>> vec_map;
    vec_map.push_back(Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd>(vec1.data(), vec1.size()));

    //Call to function
    EigenRefFunction(vec_map);
}
```

This results in compiler error C2665 on Visual Studio v142.

Edit: Sorry, just copied the generic translation. Here is the full error message from godbolt (thanks @Marek R):

> : In function 'int main()': :26:22: error: invalid
> initialization of reference of type 'const
> std::vector > >&' from
> expression of type 'std::vector, 0, Eigen::Stride > >'    26 |     EigenRefFunction(vec_map);
>       |                      ^~~~~~~ :5:71: note: in passing argument 1 of 'void EigenRefFunction(const
> std::vector > >&)'
>     5 | void EigenRefFunction(const std::vector>& vec)

If, for any reason, this is not resolvable: Is there another efficient way to store several differently sized mapped Eigen vectors in a data structure which is flexible to be extended to different sizes at runtime?

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Edit:
Thanks for all the very quick answers. Marek R provided the code to resolve my issue by simply changing the provided parameter to the function call. The resulting copy is not an issue for me:

```
EigenRefFunction({ vec_map.begin(), vec_map.end() });
```

Comment: does the error meesage really say `number1`  and `number2` ? In which line is the error?

Comment: `std::vector<Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXd>>` and `std::vector<Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd>>` are completely different types. There is no implicit conversion between them. It doesn't matter if there is conversion between `Eigen::Ref` and `Eigen::Map`.

Comment: no, `number1` and `number2` are from the generic description of C2665. You need to look at the actual error message produced by your compiler. Compiler error messages contain much more inforamtion than an error code

Comment: just because `A` can convert to `B` does not imply that `vector<A>` can convert to `vector<B>`. More generally `foo<A>` and `foo<B>` are totally unrelated types

Comment: BTW here is [your code on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1K8G1GeT5).

Comment: please include the complete errror message in the question

Comment: Here is reflectored and fixed version: https://godbolt.org/z/7EYbfMnPc note copy of `vec_map` is created.

Comment: Thank you Marek R, this is exactly, what I was looking for. So, basically the changed initialization call to EigenRefFunction with the iterators resolved my problem. Thanks again!

Comment: ```Eigen::Ref``` isn't meant to be kept around for more than a function argument and ```Maps``` are dangerous to use for this stuff because assignment overwrites the mapped data. You should make your own reference type. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72150817/pointer-to-sliced-eigen-matrix/72154852#72154852